# Не отправляются письма с помощью php

Tags: php, html

На локальном сервере OSpanel не отправляются письма.
Подскажите в чём проблема?
Сам php:

```
<?php
    $phone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $to      = "qwerty12345@gmail.com";
    $subject = "subject";
    $message =  "Имя:" .$username ."   Телефон: " .$phone;
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
?>
```

Html:

```
<form action="php/send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="phone1" alt="Your phone" placeholder="Your phone">
    </br>
    <input type="name" name="username" id="nameuser" alt="Your name" placeholder="Your name">
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send" id="button">
</form>
```

Comment: А вы настроили отправку?

Comment: Настройка отправки почты https://ospanel.io/docs/#smtp

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно условие чтобы взять данные с форм.

```
<?php
 if($_POST['send']) {
   $phone = $_POST['telephone'];
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $to      = "qwerty12345@gmail.com";
   $subject = "subject";
   $message =  "Имя:" .$username ."   Телефон: " .$phone;
   mail($to, $subject, $message);
  }

?>
```

Если письмо не в `Входящие`, будет в папке `Спам`

PS: Сам щас перезаписал весь код и письмо отправилось.

Comment: А для отправки с сайта размещенного на хостинге всё также?

Comment: if($_POST['send']) { - условие не обязательно.

Comment: @Nilsan спасибо

Comment: На сайте то же самое. Но без условия при открытии страницы запрос пойдет сразу и с пустыми полями